# Question on exponential growth

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On March 13th 2020, the cumulative number of Covid-19 cases worldwide
was approximately 145200. It was around 272400 the following week.
Predict the cumulative number of Covid-19 cases worldwide on April 10th
2020, assuming the percentage increase remains constant.

My attempt:

Percentage increase =
$\frac{(272400-145200)}{145200} \times 100 = 87.6\%$

Multiplier for percentage increase $= 100\% + 87.6\% = 1.876$

Number of cases after (t) weeks $= 145200(1.876)^{t}$

Number of cases after (4) weeks
$= 145200(1.876)^{4} = 1798448$ cases.

Thank you for taking the time to let me know if I'm on the right track, and please let me know if you have any alternative methods to recommend.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do not take into account the effect of Dr Fauci on the spread of the virus.

Comment: Question hard to read.  Please edit your question, using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to display all of the Math.

Comment: @SteveKass: 4 weeks.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience; I was having latex issues; I am still learning and hope to be proficient soon.

Comment: It seems you are trying to use the compound interest formula, somewhat. Remember that $t$ is in years, not weeks. What do you have to divide by to make it years?

Comment: Sorry if my earlier comment was confusing. This looks good to me.